# How to obtain user's choice in a radio buttons group box for further processing?

Tags: c++, user-interface, radio-button, wt

I just finished with my web application's GUI part, which relies heavily on groups of radio buttons to provide an option mechanism.

I am looking to collect user choices from radio button groups in order to provide input parameters in certain algorithms.

Wt has not a connection function of this kind declared in its `WRadioButton` class and the way of creating radio buttons makes uneasy to store user's radio button choice.

How can I proceed on this?

UPDATE: I tried to obtain choices by using `checkedButton()` (declared in `WRadioButton` class) but my method didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to look at the methods and signals of WButtonGroup: selectedId(), which returns the id of the selected WRadioButton, or checkedChanged(), which is called when the selection changes, with the checked button. checkedButton() on the WButtonGroup should work too.

Comment: I've already done this and it worked. checkedId() has an equal effect also.

Answer (score 0):

You also could connect all signals to one slot with  Wt::WSignalMapper